# When will the GRE Subject Test resume after COVID-19?

Tags: gre, covid-19

A far as my research can find, ETS has waived rescheduling fees for taking the GRE and has canceled all test dates for all tests through September 2020. They also have an *at home* option for the general test. However, I am unable to find any information regarding what the future of the subject tests will be. I need to take the mathematics subject test pretty soon to make certain application deadlines, and cannot find information anywhere I have looked regarding when it will be available again.

My questions are these. When will we be able to register for the subject tests again? If this is unknown, is *anything* known regarding the future of the test?

Comment: Only they can answer. Very possibly they don't know themselves at this point. You can hope that things will be normal later in the year, but no one can guarantee it.

Comment: And, given that tests are delayed, one would suppose the inability to take the tests would be taken into account by the institutions you are applying to. They are all dealing with any number of exceptions to long standing rules and traditions...

Comment: You both make good points. I will try to find out more about what my institutions will be doing.

Comment: This is opinion-based until ETS announces it.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I'm sorry, but I don't think you can call this question opinion-based. The question specifically includes an alternate question for the case that ETS has not announced anything, and the answer to that alternate question is objectively either yes (in which case I hope details are provided) or no. Opinions are not elicited, and opinion has nothing to do with the question statement. How can I get the question re-opened so that people can continue to post relevant information?

Comment: You should use the ETS website for information about test dates.  This isn't a good place for that.  If the information is not from ETS, it is an opinion.  If it is from ETS, why do you need to ask here?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist To answer your question, the fact that my own search was unsuccessful does not imply that others may not be able to find information I was not, whether it be because of more effective search techniques or other factors. The answer given below is evidence of that, being a reference to an ETS statement which I was not able to locate on my own. I maintain that the question is not opinion-based, and that the closure should be undone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ETS has now clarified their [policy](https://www.ets.org/gre/important_update/test_cancel) -- no subject tests until April 2021 at the earliest. As stated in the comments (and at the link), test takers should contact their prospective grad schools for instructions about how to proceed given this.